# How do I brute force an object's values?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of objects that have numerical coordinates (x,y) and a name.

I want to brute force the x and y for every value of x and y in a range. (Say [0,1,2,3,4,5])

```
var variables = {"aboutTitle_x": 0, "aboutTitle_y": 0}
let f = (a, b) => [].concat(...a.map(a => b.map(b => [].concat(a, b))));
let cartesian = (a, b, ...c) => b ? cartesian(f(a, b), ...c) : a;


var candidates = cartesian(Object.keys(variables), [0, 1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log(candidates);
```

I am using the cartesian product and this gives me every assignment, like so:

```
["aboutTitle_x", 0]
["aboutTitle_x", 1]
["aboutTitle_x", 2]
["aboutTitle_x", 3]
["aboutTitle_x", 4]
["aboutTitle_x", 5]
["aboutTitle_y", 0]
["aboutTitle_y", 1]
["aboutTitle_y", 2]
["aboutTitle_y", 3]
```

How do I iterate over potential combinations of (aboutTitle_x, aboutTitle_y). What I want is some thing like this:

```
{aboutTitle_x: 0, aboutTitle_y: 0}
{aboutTitle_x: 0, aboutTitle_y: 1}
{aboutTitle_x: 0, aboutTitle_y: 2}
{aboutTitle_x: 0, aboutTitle_y: 3}
{aboutTitle_x: 0, aboutTitle_y: 4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive approach where you use `for` loop on values but increment keys with recursion and you also pass object reference as current value.

```js
var variables = {
  "aboutTitle_x": 0,
  "aboutTitle_y": 0
}

function cartesian(keys, values, k = 0, tmp = {}) {
  const r = [];

  if (k >= keys.length) {
    r.push({ ...tmp });
    return r;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    Object.assign(tmp, {[keys[k]]: values[i]})
    r.push(...cartesian(keys, values, k + 1, tmp))
  }

  return r;
}


var candidates = cartesian(Object.keys(variables), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(candidates);
```

You could also do this using `reduce` method instead of `for` loop.

```js
var variables = {
  "aboutTitle_x": 0,
  "aboutTitle_y": 0
}

function cartesian(keys, values, k = 0, tmp = {}) {
  return values.reduce((r, e) => {
    tmp[keys[k]] = e;

    if (k >= keys.length - 1) {
      r.push({ ...tmp});
      return r;
    }

    r.push(...cartesian(keys, values, k + 1, tmp))
    return r;
  }, [])
}


var candidates = cartesian(Object.keys(variables), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(candidates);
```

You could also use recursion with ***generator*** that will give you control over each iteration.

```js
var variables = {
  "aboutTitle_x": 0,
  "aboutTitle_y": 0
}

function* cartesian(keys, values, k = 0, tmp = {}) {
  if (k >= keys.length) {
    yield { ...tmp }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      Object.assign(tmp, { [keys[k]]: values[i] })
      yield* cartesian(keys, values, k + 1, tmp)
    }
  }
}

var it = cartesian(Object.keys(variables), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

for (let i of it) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: @user10662977 Check out solution with generator.

Comment: I used the generator solution. It works! To see what you helped fix, it's this: https://github.com/samsquire/additive-guis You can Download layout/layouter.html it and run it on your PC if you want to see it working

Answer (score 1):

You could take a slightly different approach and store an object with possible values (which works nested as well) and as result you get an array of all possible values of the given properties.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    data = { aboutTitle_x: values, aboutTitle_y: values },
    cartesian = getCartesian(data);

console.log(cartesian);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works really well. I just run out of memory if the solution is far into the resulting list. Do you know how you would make this a generator. That's what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: do you have only two properties, or more. mayb a more simplified version would work, too.

Comment: Thank you by the way. I have an arbitrary number of properties.